# error when saving bitmap as image in android studio

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I cant save the bitmap in my internal storage, when looking at the logcat, it says that "java.io.IOException: No such file or directory"

here is my code

```
public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY );
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        Log.d("hhhhh",wallpaperDirectory.toString());
    }

    try {
        File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{f.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
        fo.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";

}
```

I didnt know what I'm doing wrong, help is much appreciated

Comment: You need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to write there. On Android 6.0, you need to request it at runtime as well. On Android 10, you need `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the `<application>` in the manifest to let that permission still work. And you cannot write here on Android 11+.

Comment: ouh, i did it and it finally work, thank you for your help